# Reading From RealtimeDatabase For a Specific Node

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

My Firebase RealtimeDatabase Contains a Table called Records. In that table there are FirebaseUser Uid's, in each Uid there are dates and in each date there is a list of products.
[This is an example from the firebase console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoFib.png)

In an activity called DailyTableActivity there is a button prompting to DatePickerDialog and a ListView element which should show the products of a specific date from the dialog (or the current date) for the connected User.

This is class Product

```
    import java.util.Comparator;

public class Product  {
    public Product() {

    }

    private String id;
    private String Name;
    private double Cal;
    private double Carb;
    private double Prot;
    private double Fat;
    private String Unit;
    private int Def;

    public Product(String name, int cal, int carb, int prot, int fat, String unit, int def,String id) {
        Name = name;
        Cal = cal;
        Carb = carb;
        Prot = prot;
        Fat = fat;
        Unit = unit;
        Def = def;
        this.id=id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public double getCal() {
        return Cal;
    }

    public void setCal(double cal) {
        Cal = cal;
    }

    public double getCarb() {
        return Carb;
    }

    public void setCarb(double carb) {
        Carb = carb;
    }

    public double getProt() {
        return Prot;
    }

    public void setProt(double prot) {
        Prot = prot;
    }

    public double getFat() {
        return Fat;
    }

    public void setFat(double fat) {
        Fat = fat;
    }

    public String getUnit() {
        return Unit;
    }

    public void setUnit(String unit) {
        Unit = unit;
    }

    public int getDef() {
        return Def;
    }

    public void setDef(int def) {
        Def = def;
    }


    public static Comparator<Product> productComparator= new Comparator<Product>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Product o1, Product o2) {
            return o1.getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(o2.getName().toLowerCase());
        }
    };
}
```

This is my code to read data:

```
public void getRecordOfDate( String date , final DataStatus dataStatus)
{
    final String currId= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    date="D_"+date;
    DatabaseReference recordsOfUser=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("records").child(currId);
    DatabaseReference dateRef=recordsOfUser.child(date);
    dateRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()){
                List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot keyNode : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    products.clear();
                    keys.add(keyNode.getKey());
                    Product product = keyNode.getValue(Product.class);
                    Log.d("DATA_SUCCESS", "Adding product " + product.getName());
                    products.add(product);
                    dataStatus.DataIsLoaded(products, keys);
            }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });


}
```

dataStatus is an interface which works fine, which is why I did not include it here.
I think my main problem comes from dates not existing, however even if I choose a date that exists it doesn't work.

I do think it is important to mention that if I choose a date that exists in hard code, data is read, like this:

`DatabaseReference dateRef=recordsOfUser.child("D_21_05_2021");`

I do appreciate any help and support and I hope you can help me find a solution to this problem, as I am not very familiar with NoSQL databases and I want to explore the possibilities of Realtime.

Comment: You should share your datsabase .json or an screenshot of the nodes you are working on

Comment: I added a link with a photo, please check it out...

Comment: which type of variable is `date` where you make the `DatabaseReference`?

Comment: I also don't understand why do you clear your `products` list each `for` iteration
to read data i would create a variable for each `date="D_"+date;` node and then save a `product` with those variables. But i think your reading code its ok, i don't see the issue, seems like you are situating the reference on the nodes right

Comment: I do not have a variable for it because I don't need to access it directly.

Comment: a date includes a number of products, I think a variable just for the date is irrelevant

Comment: try what i commented above, code looks good. I know that what i said its the same as what you're doing but sometimes android does weird stuff

Comment: I don't exactly understand what are you saying I should try, could you explain further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String public void getRecordOfDate( String date , final DataStatus dataStatus){
final String currId= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
date="D_"+date;
DatabaseReference recordsOfUser=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("records").child(currId);
DatabaseReference dateRef=recordsOfUser.child(date);
dateRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()){
            List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
            if(snapshot.hasChild(date)){
            for (DataSnapshot keyNode : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                //products.clear();
                keys.add(keyNode.getKey());
                //Product product = keyNode.getValue(Product.class);
                String Name = keyNode.child("name").getValue().toString();
                double Cal = Double.parseDouble(keyNode.child("cal").getValue().toString());
                double Carb = Double.parseDouble(keyNode.child("carb").getValue().toString());
                double Prot = Double.parseDouble(keyNode.child("prot").getValue().toString());
                double Fat = Double.parseDouble(keyNode.child("fat").getValue().toString());
                String Unit = keyNode.child("unit").getValue().toString();
                int Def = Integer.parseInt(keyNode.child("def").getValue().toString());
                String Id = keyNode.getKey();
                Product product = new Product(Name, Cal, Carb, Prot, Fat, Unit, Def, Id);
                Log.d("DATA_SUCCESS", "Adding product " + product.getName());
                products.add(product);
                dataStatus.DataIsLoaded(products, keys);
        }
        }else{System.out.print("Date does not exist")}
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});}
```

Try like this, hope it works! Then you should be able to operate with your list to place data on `TextView` and that kind of stuff. I commented `products.clear()` line to save the list on "local" and not delete it on each iteration. If this doesn't work for you, problem must be on your date gather method or here `date="D_"+date;`

Comment: This code seems to work, the main issue is with dates that do not exist.For instance, if the first date does not exist, the code doesn't work at all anymore. Do you know how can I handle that?

Comment: try to add `if(snapshot.hasChild(date)){*add for loop here*}` and add an `else` statement with `System.out.print("Date does not exist")` to check if is working correctly

Comment: I have edit my answer, to make it easier for you to handle

Comment: the problem is not in getting the data, it's probably reading null somewhere...

Comment: It turns out the problem was in the datepicker format where I forgot to add a 0 in the month so it could not find a matching node... Thank you for your help anyway!!

Comment: No problem, glad you could solve it :D, told you it had to be something about the date